# Dynamic package loading under plackup with Starman

Tags: perl, psgi, starman

I am running a web app under plackup with starman and trying to dynamically load and instantiate packages based on user requests. I am using 'require $packageName;' to load the package where $packageName contains the name of the package, the names are stored in a config file. I then execute a known set of commands on the instance as all classes inherit from a base class and contain a set of known methods.

This works fine under Apache, but for some reason plackup is saying it cannot locate the package even though @INC contains the library path and the package names are absolute from the last directory in the lib path. That is, the package name would be Base::My::Package.

Anyone experience this issue? Do I need to update some other path within Starman? I am executing plackup with the -I flag as well as updating my environment PERL5LIB variable. I also tried `'use lib /...'` in the main app class, but none of these work.

Thanks

Comment: Example: `starman -e'my $package = "Template"; require $package; my $t = $package->new; return [200, ["Content-Type" => "text/plain"], ["ok"]];'`

Comment: This is more or less an example of what's not working.

Comment: eval "use $package"; did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` will only accept module names (e.g. Scalar::Util) when they're specified as barewords. If you give `require` a string, then it needs to be a relative path to the module (e.g. Scalar/Util.pm). You can get around this by doing the `require` inside an `eval` (the string-parameter form of `eval`), e.g. `eval "require $package"`.

See [Check the list of module installed in machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209413/check-the-list-of-module-installed-in-machine/9209646#9209646)